# Error Binding DropDownListbox with dataset?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, dataset, database-connection

I am trying to populate my listbox and can only populate it with System.Data.Datarow 5 times, witch is the amount of entry's i have in my database.

I need my list box to be linked with my Database so that i can use it to select items to make changes to, so don't want to just populate it but rather bind it.

I can't seem to find **ValueMember** and **DisplayMember** properties. I think this may be because i'm Programming in webForms.

My Code:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DBConnectionString))
{
      conn.Open();

      SqlDataAdapter daTags = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From Tag", conn);

      DataSet dsTags = new DataSet("TagCloud");

      daTags.FillSchema(dsTags, SchemaType.Source, "Tag");
      daTags.Fill(dsTags, "Tag");

      daTags.MissingSchemaAction = MissingSchemaAction.AddWithKey;
      daTags.Fill(dsTags, "Tag");

      DataTable tblTag;
      tblTag = dsTags.Tables["Tag"];

      dplTags.DataSource = dsTags;
      dplTags.DataMember = "Tag"; 
      dplTags.DataBind();
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also specify the [DataValueField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datavaluefield.aspx)(ValueMember) and [DataTextField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.datatextfield.aspx)(DisplayMember) properties.

Comment: How as i said in my question i can find ValueMember and DisplayMember.

Comment: The DropDownList class provides the DataValueField and DataTextField properties which are equivalents to ValueMember and DisplayMember.

Comment: Thanks i just check that out it works. Quick question so i would set my DatavalueField should be "TagID" and DataTextField "Value", This way when i say listbox.selected Value or Item? i can then use the TagID to make changes though stored procedures?